# How to use PlatformGameInstance instead of GameInstance

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I know how to use game instance, but when googling PlatformGameInstance , only get information but not how to use it.

any idea?

Comment: If you want to import it into your game, create a blueprint which is derived from PlatformGameInstance. If that is not your question, please populate it with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how and what is the different between it and GameInstance.

Inside PlatformGameInstance , you can easily bind event such as on application enter background and enter foreground on mobile phones , you cant achieve the same thing with regular game instance bec it will not work, at least on my case.

I hope it will help someone else